# Using MSAL with Azure AD B2C to login with Google

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL to connect to Azure AD B2C.

I am trying to use the following example from GitHub, changing the authority, b2c scopes and client_id to mine:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp

When I try to open the login pop up I get the following error:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

How can I know which of the parameters are wrong and how do I know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I was missing the Reply URL on the web API (http://localhost:6420 for the example).